# Upload file to Google Drive with WebClient

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0, webclient

In PowerShell v2 I am trying to upload a file to Google Drive. Since v2 has no `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet I have to use .NET class `WebClient`.

Reference: https://www.connorcg.com/uploading-and-downloading-from-google-drive-via-api-with-powershell-and-oauth2.html

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $AccessToken")
$webclient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", 'multipart/related; boundary=boundary')
$webclient.Headers.Add("Content-Length", $UploadBody.Length) # This is wrong, why?
$webclient.UploadString($URL, "POST", $UploadBody)
```

Exception:

> 'Content-Length' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.

```
PS> $Error[0].Exception.ToString()
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling
"UploadString" with "3" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient
request."
---> System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
---> System.ArgumentException: The 'Content-Length' header must be modified
using the appropriate property or method.
```

Without "Content-Type" the uploaded file goes to root folder and contains my HTML body.

Without 'Content-Length' the upload is successful and everything looks good.

I still don't understand why 'Content-Length' header is wrong and what is the purpose of this. Is it mandatory in terms of possible failures/drops or proper encoding?

Comment: What if you try `$webclient.Headers.Set("Content-Length", $UploadBody.Length)`?

Comment: Also, I think `Content-Length` wants a Byte size, so depending on what is inside your $UploadBody, you can try getting this byte size using `$UploadByteSize = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetByteCount($UploadBody)` or `$UploadByteSize = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetByteCount($UploadBody)` if it is plain ASCII.

Comment: Still does not work, same integer is returned like $UploadBody.Length. The exception is the same related to wrong 'Content-Length'.